# Last element from a list using method

Tags: python, list, oop

I am trying to obtain the last position from my list generated in the following way:

```
X = ['A','B','C']  
Y = ['1','2','3']

class Combination:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        if (x in X) and (y in Y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        else:
            print "WRONG!!"

    def __str__ (self):
        return x+y

class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xy = []
        for i in X:
            for j in Y:
                self.xy.append(Combination(i,j))

    def choose_last(self):
        return self.xy.pop()

    def __str__(self):
        return "List contains: " + str(self.xy)

P1 = Position()
print P1
P2 = Position.choose_last()
print P2
```

My result is:

```
List contains: [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3]

Line 30: TypeError: choose_last() takes exactly 1 arguments (0 given)
```

As I'm new to OOP I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: It happens because you are trying to access an instance method as a class method. Change P2 = Position().choose_last()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the last item of a list with `[-1]`:

```
>>> lst = range(10)
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst[-1]
9
```

`pop` will remove the item from the list.

---

Regardless, you are using classes wrong.

In this specific case - you should do:

```
pos = Position()
print pos
last_item = pos.choose_last()
print last_item
```

Instead of:

```
P1 = Position()
print P1
P2 = Position.choose_last()
print P2
```

Comment: I want to remove it from the list because I don't want to use it any more and before last element was last then. Anyway after changing the code I got exactly the same error.

Comment: That is not possible. Please replace the last 4 lines in your sample with the lines I supplied.

Comment: Sorry I didn't change the first line. Now it works, perfectly :) Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
List contains: [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3]

Line 30: TypeError: choose_last() takes exactly 1 arguments (0 given)
```

This is because you call choose_last() for a class, not object. In Python all methods called for instance of a class (for object) have an implicit first argument: `self`

In other words, calling `P1.choose_last()` is exactly like:

```
Position.choose_last(P1)
```

Interpreter wants you to pass one parameter, `self`, or to call the method for the object, not class. Of course calling methods for objects is the preferred OOP way to do, because you can write code not knowing exact class of the object - objects you manipulate can be [polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Subtyping).

From the Python documentation:

> Actually, you may have guessed the answer: the special thing about
>   methods is that the object is passed as the first argument of the
>   function. In our example, the call x.f() is exactly equivalent to
>   MyClass.f(x). In general, calling a method with a list of n arguments
>   is equivalent to calling the corresponding function with an argument
>   list that is created by inserting the method’s object before the first
>   argument.

As for the retrieving the last element from the list, by convention negative indexes mean 'I'm counting from the end':

```
def choose_last(self):
    return self.xy[-1]
```